# On login, I am only given the Guest user option. How do I log into my account?

Tags: user-account, login, guest-account, login-screen

I tried to add a guest account to my laptop and when I restarted the computer, the only login option I have is the Guest Account.  Choosing this account restarts the computer into the Safari-only configuration.  There is no Systems Preferences available in this mode.

I did not unchoose my administrator account.  How did this happen?  And how do I get it back?

Comment: Let's see whether we can narrow this down a bit: Which OS X version are you using? Do you FireVault enabled? What happens if you log in as Guest and then log out again, are the other logins displayed then? While logged in as Guest, can you use Fast User Switching to log in as another user?

Answer (score 1):

I think safe mode would work better. Here are the instructions, from the Apple Support website

> To start up into Safe Mode (to Safe Boot), do this:
>
> 1. Be sure your Mac is shut down.
> 2. Press the power button.
> 3. Immediately after you hear the startup tone, hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. The <kbd>Shift</kbd> key should be held as soon as possible after the startup
>      tone, but not before the tone.
> 4. Release the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the gray Apple icon and the
>      progress indicator (looks like a spinning gear).

Once your in, go to **System Preferences** and disable Find My Mac (iCloud settings) and Guest User (Users and Groups). **Reboot.** You should be able to login normally. If you would still like a guest user, just go back and enable Find My Mac.

Answer (score -2):

Try restarting the computer by clicking at the Apple logo () in the upper left screen corner and choosing **Restart**.